# Retrieving data from a DB and send it via mail

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, pymysql

I am creating a script that takes some data from a database and then it sends it via mail. Unfortunately, I am stuck with something that seems very easy to do.

If there is only one entry from the DB it works perfectly (ex: 18/10/18 - Do math exercises) but if there are multiple entries they don't show up, I thought about using a while loop but as I have to keep all the entries in the same variable I can't get it working. I share the code below:

```
# Enviar correu Python 3.6 (NO ANOMENAR EMAIL.PY)
import smtplib, pymysql.cursors, secrets, re, datetime
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from time import strftime

def dbb():
    connection = pymysql.connect(host='X',
                                 user='root',
                                 password='X',
                                 db='deuresc',
                                 charset='utf8mb4',
                                 cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    try:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            # Llegim tots els recordatoris
            dataactual = strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            data = datetime.datetime.strptime(dataactual, "%Y-%m-%d")
            datafinal = data + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
            sql = "SELECT * FROM `deures` WHERE `data`=%s"
            cursor.execute(sql, datafinal)
            resultat = cursor.fetchall()

            for row in resultat:
                data = str(row['data'])
                print(data)
                tasca = str(row['tasca'])
                print(tasca)
                # It prints all the values but it doesn't send them below.
            fromaddr = "X"
            PASSWORD = "X"

            welcome = ['Jefe', 'Gery', 'Boss', 'Gary']

            # Misstage del correu
            SUBJECT = "Recordatori deures " + data
            body = "Bon dia " + secrets.choice(welcome) + ',' +  '\n' + 'Tens les següents tasques programades per demà: ' + '\n' + data + ' ' + tasca
            toaddr = "X"

            try:
                msg = MIMEMultipart()
                msg['From'] = fromaddr
                msg['To'] = toaddr
                msg['Subject'] = SUBJECT

                msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

                # Detalles del servidor de correu (Gmail, SMTP, Port: 587, TLS)
                server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
                server.starttls()
                server.login(fromaddr, PASSWORD)
                text = msg.as_string()
                server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
                server.quit()
                print("S'ha enviat el recordatori a '" + toaddr + "' satisfactoriament!")
            except:
                print("S'ha produït un error!")
    finally:
        connection.close()
```

Thanks in advance for your help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping over the results and assigning the values `data` and `tasca` inside the loop.  When the loop is done, those two variables will only contain the last one which was printed of each respective value.

Examine:

```
>>> for value in range(3):
...    print(value)
...
0
1
2
>>> print(value)
2
```

If you want to print all values, you have to store them somewhere.

You probably want something like

```
datas = []  # list to remember the data values
tascas = []  # list to remember the tasca values
for row in resultat:
    data = str(row['data'])
    print(data)
    datas.append(data)  # store this data in the list
    tasca = str(row['tasca'])
    print(tasca)
    tascas.append(tasca)  # store this tasca in the list
```

... and then later on in the code

```
body = "Bon dia " + secrets.choice(welcome) + ',' +  '\n' + \
     'Tens les següents tasques programades per demà: ' + '\n' + \
     '\n'.join(datas) + ' ' + '\n'.join(tascas)
```

If you expect the values to be printed next to each other in the email message, the collecting loop should probably instead look something like

```
data_tasca = []  # list to remember data/tasca pairs
for row in resultat:
    ...
    data_tasca.append(' '.join([data, tasca]))
```

and then in the `body` assignment collect the rows from `data_tasca` similarly to how the collected values from `datas` and `tascas` are collected above.

As an aside, you should probably move the code which doesn't use `cursor` to be outside the `with` clause, i.e. outdent the code after `cursor.fetchall()`.

Comment: It is working now. I don't know if it was my fault (or yours) but it is not possible to join two arguments, it takes only one. I have appended them to the same list using the join but seppartely.